# creating new Array() constructor with number and string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Actually, I am working on someone others code.

While resolving a bug I found
such types of things.

Note: API is giving productNumber in number type.

> Sometimes passing only one productNumber in new Array(). then a new
>   bug occurs.
>
> And when entering productNumber more than one then working fine.
>
> Why arr1[0] is giving undefined.

```js
var productNumber1 = 1001;
var arr1 = new Array(productNumber1);
console.log("arr1",arr1[0]);

var productNumber2 = '1001';
var arr2 = new Array(productNumber2);
console.log("arr2",arr2[0]);
```

Could you please someone explain this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In case1 the argument you passing getting treated as a length of the array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

> A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements, **except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array constructor and that argument is a number (see the arrayLength parameter below)**. Note that this special case only applies to JavaScript arrays created with the Array constructor, not array literals created with the bracket syntax.
>
> arrayLength
>
> **If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2^32-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values).** If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

So actually in case1, you are creating an array with length `1001`.

However in case 2, that is getting treated as an element since it's not a number.

Comment: Just a small correction: one doesn't pass a parameter, but an *argument* instead. Parameters never change, arguments do.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ahh avoided that confusion.

Comment: So "any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown" means (productNumber<0 || productNumber>2^32-1) will produce an exception.

Comment: @AnkitPandey Cool. Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is described in the [documentation for the Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number

So if you pass a number like `1001` you'll set the length, but if you pass a string like `'1001'`, you'll set the first value, and if you pass multiple arguments you will set multiple values.

---

Just don't use the Array constructor. Use the square bracket literal notation instead. That avoids the problem.

```js
var productNumber1 = 1001;
var arr1 = [productNumber1];
console.log("arr1",arr1[0]);

var productNumber2 = '1001';
var arr2 = [productNumber2];
console.log("arr2",arr2[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the `Array.of()` tool for this job.

```js
var p1 = 1001,
    p2 = "1001",
    a1 = Array.of(p1),
    a2 = Array.of(p2);

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
```

Comment: Nice solution of my question.
Array.of() is part of es6.